# How to use jQuery.validationEngine in ajax field validation with php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/) framework with [jQuery.validationEngine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine).

In my controller:

```
public function check_email() {
    $email = get_post('fieldValue');
    $is_unique = User_Model::is_email_unique($email);
    $to_js = array(
        get_post('fieldId'),
        $is_unique
    );
    echo json_encode($to_js);
}
```

In my view:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#form_id').validationEngine('attach');
});
</script>
...
...
<input id="email" class="validate[required,custom[email],ajax[check_email_unique]]" type="text" value="" name="email">
```

But it doesn't work. I don't know where should I put the URL (ie. http://localhost/user/check_email)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with validation engine but if your problem is to addressing, do like this:

`http://localhost/yourprojectname/index.php/checkMail`

If you omitted the `index.php` using rewriting so just remove it from the URL and of course your default controller must be set as the controller of the checkMail function.

Comment: The problem is I doesn't really know how the validationEngine work